# Exporting and importing a MATLAB map structure

Tags: matlab, data-structures, dictionary, export

I'm using the containers.Map-function to store my data.

Is there an easy way to export the whole structure to a file and be able to import it again at a later time.

A structure could be:

```
keys = {'six','seven','eight','nine'};
vals = {6,7,8,9};

Map = containers.Map(keys,vals);
```

and then say I want to export this structure and be able to import at a later time (or in another code).

Thanks, regards
Rasmus

Comment: `save` and `load`? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/save-load-and-delete-workspace-variables.html

Comment: Ah, thank you.. That was exactly what I was looking for. Don't know how I would be able to miss it. Guess my search was centered on map-structure.

Comment: No problem, I guess next time google how to save and load in matlab ;) Anyway, I've posted it as an answer for you.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I tried, I just had something specific about the Map-structure instead of just searching in general terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `save` and `load` functions: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/save-load-and-delete-workspace-variables.html:

```
save('MyFileName', 'Map');
load('MyFileName');
```